# Issue with Form Submission and Data Sending to Server in React App

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering a problem with my React application. When I submit a form with user details, the form is supposed to send this data to my server to create an order, but I keep receiving the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')."

Here's how my application works:

I have a form in my React component.
When the form is submitted, I handle the form data and send it to the server to create an order.
The server is correctly set up to handle order creation, and it works perfectly when I use Postman to send a request.
However, when I submit the form from my React app, the page reloads as expected, but the data doesn't seem to be sent to the server. Moreover, I see this error in my browser console.

Here's the relevant code:

**React Component (Contact.js):**

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
    import Footer from "../../Components/Footer";
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { getOrders } from "../../actions/orders.action";
    import { createOrder } from "../../actions/order.action";
    import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    import cookie from "js-cookie";
    
    const Contact = () => {
      const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cartReducer);
      const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
      const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
      const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      console.log(cart.cartId);
      const removeCookie = (key) => {
        if (window !== "undefined") {
          cookie.remove(key, { expire: 1 });
        }
      };
    
    const handleSubmitOrder = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();  // When I remove this line, the page still reloads, but data isn't sent.
        if (username && address && phoneNumber) {
            // ... Form data handling ...
            await dispatch(createOrder(data));
            // ... Clear form ...
            navigate("/commands");  // Navigate to another page
        } else {
            alert("Please fill out all the required information.");
        }
    };
 return (
    <div>
      <header className="header">
        <div className="header__topbar">
          <Link to="/">
            <p className="header__topbar__logo">Panini</p>
          </Link>
          <div className="header__cart__desktop">
            <span className="header__topbar__cart__value"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main className="main">
        <section>
          <h1 className="form__title">Entrez vos informations</h1>
          <form className="form__container" onSubmit={handleSubmitOrder}>
            <div className="form__contain">
              <div className="form__input__container">
                <label htmlFor="name">Nom</label>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
                  value={username}
                  type="text"
                  id="name"
                  placeholder="Entrez votre nom"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form__input__container">
                <label htmlFor="location">Quartier</label>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
                  value={address}
                  type="text"
                  id="location"
                  placeholder="Entrez le nom de votre quartier"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form__input__container">
                <label htmlFor="number">N° de téléphone</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)}
                  value={phoneNumber}
                  id="number"
                  placeholder="Entrez votre numéor de téléphone "
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <input
              className="form__submit"
              type="submit"
              value="Valider votre commande"
            />
          </form>
        </section>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

**Action (orders.action.js):**

```
import axios from "axios";
export const CREATE_ORDER = "CREATE_ORDER";
export const CREATE_ORDER_SUCCESS = "CREATE_ORDER_SUCCESS";
export const CREATE_ORDER_FAILURE = "CREATE_ORDER_FAILURE";
// ... Action code ...
export const createOrder = (data) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/cart/create/orders`,
        data,
        { withCredentials: true }
      );

      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_ORDER_SUCCESS,
        payload: response.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_ORDER_FAILURE,
        payload: error.response.data,
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Reducer (order.reducer.js):

```
import {
  CREATE_ORDER_FAILURE,
  CREATE_ORDER_SUCCESS,
} from "../actions/order.action";
// ... Reducer code ...
const initialState = {
  order: null,
  error: null,
};

export default function orderReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_ORDER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        order: action.payload, // Store order details here
        error: null,
      };
    case CREATE_ORDER_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Backend (Node.js) :

Controller createOrder

```
module.exports.createOrder = async (req, res) => {
  const { cartId, username, phone_number, address, status, totalPrice } =
    req.body;

  try {
    const cart = await Cart.findByPk(cartId);
    const order = await OrderItem.findAll({
      where: { cartId: cart.id },
    });

    if (!cart.id) {
      return res.status(404).json("Cet article n'est plus disponible");
    }

    const total = await Promise.all(
      order.map(async (orderItemId) => {
        const products = await Product.findOne({
          where: { id: orderItemId.productId },
        });
        const options = await Option.findOne({
          where: { id: orderItemId.optionId },
        });
        const qty = await OrderItem.findOne({
          where: { quantity: orderItemId.quantity },
        });

        let prices;
        prices = products.price * qty.quantity;
        return prices;
      })
    );

    const totalPrices = total.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    const createOrder = await ShopOrder.create({
      orderId: cart.id,
      username,
      phone_number,
      address,
      status,
      totalPrice: totalPrices,
    });

    createOrder.save();
    res.cookie("cart", "", { maxAge: 1 });
    return res.status(201).json(createOrder);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ "error": error.message });
  }
};
```

I've noticed that even if I remove the e.preventDefault() line from the form submission handler, the page reloads, but the data isn't sent to the server and isn't saved in the database. When I use Postman to send the same request to the backend, the order is created successfully. Can anyone help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here, and it's going to be very difficult to track down what's going on without more detail. First thing to get out of the way, if you are troubleshooting a form submission without `e.preventDefault()`, page reloading is expected (albeit not a great UX), but all your network/console logs will be cleared. Suggest you turn on `Preserve log` for both Network and Console while you debug. This should allow you to see why it's failing by inspecting the console or network request/response.

Comment: Okay, I see, but what other details do you want me to give you so that you can help me?

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you until you go through the troubleshooting steps the pinpoint what's going on. Some error message, some indication of where the failure is happening.